# This really simple code should work but it doesn't

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

File name: Hello world

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String message = "Hello world";
        System.out.println(message.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

And it should work but its says

*Replace this use of System.out or System.err by a logger.*

I'm using Visual Studio Code and I can't figure out why its not working.  Did I do something wrong with setting up VS code?

Thanks

Comment: I personally am disgusted by anything "Visual Studio" (pro and community) related. Have to use those regularly. Also tried Visual Studio Code, actually gave it multiple tries. Never EVER been a good experience. So whenever possible, I steer clear of that stuff. MS and its VS(C)s just put in too many MS-specific idiosyncrasies that make handling normal code a pain in the ass. Especially throwing compile time errors when things should only be a warning...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is a common beginner mistake.

Your code is alright, you just need to fix the filename. Match the filename with the public class declared. Java needs the public class to be named the same as the filename. Fixing that should fix your error.

Name the file `HelloWorld` and you are good to go.

Comment: Neither `System.out` nor `System.err` is a file name used here.

Comment: You are right. I should have paid more attention to the question.